# How can i perform search from all website pages?

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with my search engine  in my website which is under construction and how to search from all the pages of the site
at first at index.html I create a form

In the beginning it have performed wonderfully and the search results were correct and search.php file was correct , after that I copied these statements
in all website pages ,Here lies the problem I can't perform search from other pages .....

```
<form action="search.php" class="menu_search_form">
                <input type="text" class="menu_search_input" placeholder="Search" required="required"name="search">
                <button class="menu_search_button"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</form>
```

### I want to perform search from all web pages

this is the output statement when i perform search from other pages ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server.------------------------------------------Knowing that the search leads from index.html page is all smooth

Comment: Nobody can help you with that kind of info.

Comment: "can't" is not an error message or problem statement. You will need to provide some more specific information about the issue. We can't access your page to debug it for you. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson  this is the output statement when i perform search from other pages              ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server.------------------------------------------Knowing that the search leads from index.html page is all smooth

Comment: Check the full URL being called by the request (you can use the network tool in your browser to watch for this). Are your other pages perhaps in a different folder on the server than search.php? If so then you'll need to use a suitable relative URL to make it locate the script correctly.

Comment: all pages are in the same folder

Comment: Then I don't see how it could be possible to have the stated problem, sorry. If they are all in the same folder on the same server with the same HTML code in the form, then everything should just work exactly the same. So either your reporting of the problem is incorrect or your reporting of the setup is incorrect, as far as I can tell. Since we can't see your environment, then without accurate and detailed information it's very hard to help

Comment: @ADyson Strangely, I deleted the form from the code and then saved the code and found it on the page

Answer (score 2):

- You're getting a 404 error.
- Your URL looks like: `search.php` so it is relative to the current directory

So when on `http://example.com/` the form submits to `http://example.com/search.php`.

But when on `http://example.com/cheese/`, the form submits to `http://example.com/cheese/search.php`

… and only one of those URLs is correct.

---

Write a URL that always points to the right destination. For example `/search.php`.

Comment: all pages are in the same folder